# How to bounce text in a window without JFrame?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I am trying to bounce my text in a window, inserted from a text file without modifying the inputs from the text. I have the code to create and bounce the text, but some of it is lost when trying to bounce on the wall. The code consists of 3 classes.

This creates the text:

```
public class MyShape extends ClosedShape {
    //The width and height of the text (major and minor axis)
    private int width, height;
    private String bouncingText;
    private double textFont;
    /**
     * Creates an oval.
     * @param x The display component's x position.
     * @param y The display component's y position.
     * @param vx The display component's x velocity.
     * @param vy The display component's y velocity.
     * @param width The width of the text (in pixels).
     * @param height The height of the text (in pixels).
     * @param colour The line colour or fill colour.
     * @param isFilled True if the oval is filled with colour, false if opaque.
     */
    public MyShape (int insertionTime, int x, int y, int vx, int vy, String bouncingText, int width, int height, Color colour, boolean isFilled, double textFont) {
        super (insertionTime, x, y, vx, vy, colour, isFilled);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.bouncingText = bouncingText;
        this.textFont = textFont;

    }

    /**
     * Method to convert a text to a string.
     */
    public String toString () {
        String result = "This is a text shape\n";
        result += super.toString ();
    result += "Its width is " + this.width + " and its height is " + this.height + "\n";
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param width Resets the width.
     */
    public void setWidth (int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    /**
     * @param height Resets the height.
     */
    public void setHeight (int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setBouncingText (String bouncingText) {
        this.bouncingText = bouncingText;
    }

    public void setTextFont (double textFont) {
        this.textFont = textFont;
    }
    /**
     * @return The width of the text.
     */
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * @return The height of the text.
     */
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public String getBouncingText() {
        return bouncingText;
    }

    public double getTextFont() {
        return textFont;
    }
    public void pulsing() {
        if (textFont > 20) {
            textFont = 10;
        }else {
            textFont = 50;
        }
    }



    /**
     * Draw the text.
     * @param g The graphics object of the drawable component.
     */
    public void draw (GraphicsContext g) {

        Font bouncingTextFont = new Font ("TimesNew",  textFont);

        g.setFill (colour);
        g.setStroke( colour );
        if (isFilled) {
            g.fillText(bouncingText, xPos, yPos );
            g.setFont(bouncingTextFont);

        } 
        else {
            g.strokeText(bouncingText, xPos, yPos );
            g.setFont(bouncingTextFont);
        }
    }


}
```

This is the bouncing code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class BouncingShapesWindow {

    private static final int ANIMATION_DELAY = 10;
    private static final String FRAME_TITLE = "Shape Booooiiinggg Frame";

    private GraphicsContext gc;
    private Queue shapesToAdd;
    private ArrayList<ClosedShape> activeShapes;
    private int currentTime = 0;
    private boolean flag=true;

    private String filename;


    public BouncingShapesWindow(GraphicsContext gc,String filename) {
        this.gc=gc;

        activeShapes=new ArrayList<ClosedShape>();
        this.initShapes(filename);
        this.insertShapes ();
        drawShapes();
        actionPerformed();
    }

    private void drawShapes () {
        for (ClosedShape s : activeShapes)
        {
            s.draw(gc);
        }
    }

    private void initShapes (String filename) {
        shapesToAdd = ReadShapeFile.readFile(filename);
    }

    private void insertShapes() {
        //no more shapes to add, we are done
        if (shapesToAdd.isEmpty ()) {
            return;
        }

        //add shapes if needed
        ClosedShape current = (ClosedShape) shapesToAdd.peek ();
        while (!shapesToAdd.isEmpty () && (current.getInsertionTime() <= currentTime*ANIMATION_DELAY)) {
            activeShapes.add(current);
            shapesToAdd.dequeue();
            if (!shapesToAdd.isEmpty ()) {
                current = (ClosedShape) shapesToAdd.peek();
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed()
    {

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5), ae -> onTime()));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();

    }

    private void onTime() {
        currentTime++;
        double h =gc.getCanvas().getHeight();
        double w = gc.getCanvas().getWidth();
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        moveShapes();
        insertShapes ();
        drawShapes();
    }

    public void moveShapes()
    {
        double  dimsY = gc.getCanvas().getHeight() ;
        double  dimsX = gc.getCanvas().getWidth() ;
        for (ClosedShape s : activeShapes)
        {
            s.move();

            // Move us back in and bounce if we went outside the drawing area.
            if (s.outOfBoundsX(dimsX))
            {
                s.putInBoundsX(dimsX);
                s.bounceX();
            }

            if (s.outOfBoundsY(dimsY))
            {
                s.putInBoundsY(dimsY);
                s.bounceY();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

and this is the super class:

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

/** 
 * A ClosedShape is any shape that can be drawn without
 * taking a pencil off a piece of paper.
 * It's representation on computer has a line colour
 * and a position on the drawable screen component.
 * It can be filled in with colour or opaque.
 * This class is a super class for all shapes.
 */

public class ClosedShape {

    /**
     *  The x position of the Shape.
     */
    protected int xPos;
    /**
     * The y position of the Shape.
     */
    protected int yPos = 20;

    /**
     *  The x position of the Shape.
     */
    protected int xVec;

    /**
     * The y position of the Shape.
     */
    protected int yVec;

    /**
     * The line colour of the shape, or the filled in
     * colour if the Shape has fill.
     */
    protected Color colour;

    /**
     * Determines if the Shape has a fill colour or not.
     */
    protected boolean isFilled;

    /**
     * Encodes the insertion time into the scene
     */
    private int insertionTime;

    /**
     * Creates a closed shape object.
     * @param x The x position.
     * @param y the y position.
     * @param colour The line or fill colour.
     * @param isFilled True if the shape is filled, false if not.
     */
    protected ClosedShape (int insertionTime, int x, int y, int vx, int vy, Color colour, boolean isFilled) {
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
        this.xVec = vx;
        this.yVec = vy;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.isFilled = isFilled;
        this.insertionTime = insertionTime;
    }

    /**
     * The method returns a string suitable for printing.
     * @return string to print out shape.
     */
    public String toString () {
        String result = "";
        result += "Its position is " + xPos + " " + yPos + "\n";
        result += "Its velocity is " + xVec + " " + yVec + "\n";
        result += "Its colour is " + colour + "\n";
        if (isFilled)
            result += "It is filled" + "\n";
        else
            result += "It is not filled" + "\n";
        result += "It should be inserted at " + insertionTime + "\n";
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the x position.
     */
    public void setX (int x) {
        this.xPos = x;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the y position.
     */
    public void setY (int y) {
        this.yPos = y;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the x vector
     */
     public void setVecX (int x) {
        this.xVec = x;
     }//end setVecX

    /**
     * Resets the y position.
     */
     public void setVecY (int y) {
        this.yVec = y;
    }//end setVecY

     /**
      * Resets the colour.
      */
     public void setColour (Color colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
     }

     /**
      * Sets the shape to filled.
      */
     public void setFilled () {
         isFilled = true;
     }

     /**
      * Sets the shape to unfilled.
      */
     public void unsetFilled () {
        isFilled = false;
     }

     /**
      * Sets the insertion time.
      */
     public void setInsertionTime (int time) {
         insertionTime = time;
     }

     /**
      * @return The x position value.
      */
     public int getX() {
        return xPos;
     }

     /**
      * @return The y position value.
      */
     public int getY() {
        return yPos;
     }

     /**
      * @return The colour.
      */
     public Color getColour() {
        return colour;
     }

     /**
      * @return True if the shape is filled, false if not.
      */
     public boolean isFilled() {
        return isFilled;
     }

     /**
      * @return the insertion time.
      */
     public int getInsertionTime () {
         return insertionTime;
     }

     /**
      * Puts the shape back in bounds in X
      */
     public void putInBoundsX (double winX) {
        if (xPos < 0) xPos = 0;
        if (xPos + this.getWidth() > winX) {
            xPos = (int) (winX - Math.ceil (this.getWidth ()));
        }
     }//end inBoundsX;

     /**
      * Puts the shape back in bounds
      */
     public void putInBoundsY (double winY) {
        if (yPos < 0) yPos = 0;
        if (yPos + this.getHeight() > winY) {
            yPos = (int) (winY - Math.ceil (this.getHeight ()));
        }
     }//end inBoundsY;

     /**
      * Bounces the shape off a vertical wall
      */
     public void bounceX () {
        xVec = -xVec;
     }

     /**
      * Bounces the shape off a horizontal wall
      */
     public void bounceY () {
        yVec = -yVec;
     }

     /**
      * Returns true if the shapes have gone out of bounds in X
      */
     public boolean outOfBoundsX (double winX) {
        return (xPos + this.getWidth()> winX) || (xPos < 0);
     }

     /**
      * Returns true if the shapes have gone out of bounds in Y
      */
     public boolean outOfBoundsY (double winY) {
        return (yPos + this.getHeight() > winY) || (yPos < 0);
     }

     /**
      * Takes in a direction and a velocity and moves the shape
      * in that direction on unit
      */
     public void move () {
        xPos += xVec;
        yPos += yVec;
     }

     /**
      * Draws the object to the current component.
      * @param g The graphics object associated with the drawing component.
      */
     public void draw (GraphicsContext g) {
        System.out.println ("You forgot to override this method! (draw)");
        System.out.println ("Don't modify this method.");
     }

     /**
      * Get the width of the current component
      */
     public int getWidth () {
        System.out.println ("You forgot to override this method! (getWidth)");
        System.out.println ("Don't modify this method.");
        return 1;
     }

     /**
      * Get the width of the current component
      */
     public int getHeight () {
        System.out.println ("You forgot to override a method! (getHeight)");
        System.out.println ("Don't modify this method.");
        return 1;
     }

     public int getSide () {
            System.out.println ("You forgot to override this method! (getSide)");
            System.out.println ("Don't modify this method.");
            return 1;
         }

}
```

I tried reversing it, but nothing works. Using other shapes like circle or rect is OK, but with text it bounces under the head of the window and if I change the font size it loses its boundaries. I tried searching for solutions and it seems that everything uses `JFrame` and `JPanel`. I hope the code I provided leads to a useful solution.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"How to bounce text in a window without JFrame?"* Well, one way is to not use Swing. You might instead use Java-FX, which I note it in the tags. So .. which GUI toolkit is being used (note, would become obvious with an MCVE) & if Swing, why ***not*** use a `JFrame`?

Comment: The thing is that my text bounces of the window when it is pulsing. I tried to reverse the direction if its length is more than the window but nothing happens. So according to my code I show you above I think if I do this it will work.

Comment: 1) There is still three separate public classes above but no single `main` method, so there is still no MCVE. 2) I'm not sure what you intended by adding those words but there is still no answer to my question in point (2) above. Voting to close.